# Trying to run NASA GMAT on Ubuntu 20.04, I get the error "no main manifest attribute, in gmat.jar"

Tags: nasa, gmat, linux

I downloaded GMAT from `https://software.nasa.gov/software/GSC-17177-1`
Then I extracted using `tar -zxf gmat-ubuntu-x64-R2020a.tar.gz`
Then I went to the `bin` folder and set `gmat.jar` as an executable (`rightclick -> properties -> permissions`).
Finally when I tried `java -jar gmat.jar`, I get

```
no main manifest attribute, in gmat.jar
```

Comment: Note to potential close voters: software questions about certain topics (e.g. for anything space or orbital mechanics related and certainly anything GMAT-related) *have always been on-topic here!* While some are also on-topic in Stack Overflow, there are GMAT users here who may be familiar with just this case. If no answers arise, this can always be moved to SO later.

Comment: I'm not able to try this out myself at the moment, but looking at https://sourceforge.net/projects/gmat/files/GMAT/GMAT-R2016a/ it appears to me that it is not intended to be run directly from the jar. Likely the jar manifest does not include `Main-Class: ` .  You can confirm by extracting the jar as a zip file and looking at the text of `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`.  Try running `GmatConsole` or `Gmat_Beta` instead as a regular executable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GMAT is written primarily in C++.

`gmat.jar` is an api wrapper to allow java code to access the core functionality as explained at http://gmat.sourceforge.net/docs/R2020a/api/userguide/GettingStarted.html

In other words, `gmat.jar` would be used if you wanted to write your own java program that interacted with gmat functionality.

Running the gmat application is explained at https://sourceforge.net/projects/gmat/files/GMAT/GMAT-R2016a/

> On Linux, open a terminal window and change directories to the GMAT bin
> folder.  The GMAT command line program is executed by running the GmatConsole
> application in that folder:
>
> ./GmatConsole
>
> The Beta GUI can be run using the same terminal window by running Gmat_Beta:
>
> ./Gmat_Beta
>
> Linux users can create a launcher for either the command line application or
> the GUI application by following the instructions for that process for their
> Linux distribution.

## Version Notes

The links from the NASA page to the sourceforge link can be a bit confusing.  To make sure you are getting the instructions for the version you are downloading, navigate through https://sourceforge.net/projects/gmat/files/GMAT/ to the version you want to use.

- On 2021-09-18, clicking "download" from the OP link (https://software.nasa.gov/software/GSC-17177-1) takes you to https://sourceforge.net/projects/gmat/files/GMAT/GMAT-R2016a/. *this is not the latest version*.
- Clicking the "Download latest version" on the sourceforge page will (as of 2021-09-18) give you version R2020a.
- R2020a executable notes are at https://sourceforge.net/projects/gmat/files/GMAT/GMAT-R2020a/, which includes this additional notice:

> UBUNTU 18.04 Note:  Ubuntu 18.04 does not ship with libpng12.so, used by
> the wxWidgets libraries bundled with the Ubuntu installation.  You can
> download the needed library from the Ubuntu packages site
>
> https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download
>
> Download the package and install it using the Ubuntu package manager.

The same page contains run instructions for other platforms as well.

Comment: Thank you! This works!
Ran "sudo apt install libopengl0 -y" to fix a library error.